# How to call some function from the Flask app in Python?

Tags: python, flask

I've the `myapp.py` like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
         # do something
         # for example:
         message = 'I am from the POST method'
         f = open('somefile.out', 'w')
         print(message, f)

    return render_template('test.html', out='Hello World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I have a simple question. **How to call the `index()` function and execute code only in the `if` statement (line from 8 to 13) in the Python?**

I tried in this way:

```
>>> import myapp
>>> myapp.index()
```

but I get the message:

```
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

Comment: `http://localhost:5000/` works fine in a browser though? Just checking what you are really stuck on.

Comment: I was wondering about the capabilities of calling flask functions standalone outside of the `__main__` context. Ideally I would be able to reuse all the view rendering from an offline context, that is not from the flask app session but another python module which automated rendering the templates from some scheduler by writing to disk a bunch of static pages whose content was generated by the flask functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [Request Context](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reqcontext/) documentation; you need to create a context explicitly:

```
>>> ctx = myapp.app.test_request_context('/', method='POST')
>>> ctx.push()
>>> myapp.index()
```

You can also use the context as a context manager (see [Other Testing Tricks](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing/#other-testing-tricks)):

```
>>> with myapp.app.test_request_context('/', method='POST'):
...     myapp.index()
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by accessing the `request.method` attribute in the `index()` function. You could call `index()` without any problems unless you try to access the `request` attributes inside it.

The `request` proxy works only within a [request context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/).

You can read more aboout it here:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/

```
>>> request.method
(...)
>>> RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

You can create a request context like this:

```
>>> with app.test_request_context('/'):
...     request.method
... 
'GET'
```